# Copy data in 1 row in Sheet 1 to changed data in 2 rows of Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA.

I have a `10` digit number (1234567890) in `A1` of `Sheet 1` and want to copy this data in `A1` in `sheet 2` with a concatenated value (-qwerty) and again in `A2` in `sheet 2` with another concatenated value (-abcdef). So the final values in `A1` of Sheet `2` will be `1234567890-qwerty` and in `A2` of `Sheet 2` will be `1234567890-abcdef`

Similarly, I want to fill `n` rows of `A` column in `sheet 1` to `2n` rows of `A` column in `Sheet 2`.

Looking out for VBA help in excel for the same. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I think no need a VBA

just write in excel's Sheet2 column A1, a formula

```
= Sheet1.A1 & "-qwerty"
```

and just write in excel's Sheet2 column A2, a formula

```
= Sheet1.A1 & "-abcdef"
```

or something like that

Comment: Maybe `= Sheet1!A1 & "-qwerty"`.

Comment: I do need VBA because this is a very small part of a huge macro.

Answer (score 0):

Direct value transfer with a string concatenation would seem to be the easiest.

```
sheet2.cells(1,1) = sheet1.cells(1, 1).value2 & "-qwerty"
sheet2.cells(2,1) = sheet1.cells(1, 1).value2 & "-abcdef"
```

Bulk transfer can be accomplished with a simple formula and more string concatenation.

```
with sheet2.cells(1,1).resize(99,1)
    .formula = "='Sheet1'!A1&"-qwerty"
    .value = .value
end with
```

After the formula has been filled, the value in the cell is reverted to the value from the formula (thereby removing the formula).

Comment: To be true, I still did not understand how to use it.